# How to fetch data from mongodb using nodejs, expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

**Here is my code
file name student.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    rollno:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    grade:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    result:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});


var Student = module.exports = mongoose.model('Student',studentSchema);


module.exports.getStudents = function (callback){

    Student.find(callback);
}

**filename app.js**

var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var PORT= process.env.PORT || 3000;


Student = require('./models/student');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/register');

var db= mongoose.connection;

app.get('/api/student', function (req,res){

    Student.getStudents(function (err, student){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(student);
    });
});


app.listen(PORT);

console.log('Running app on port:' + PORT);
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: i cant get the collections data in mongodb to display on the html page

Comment: Are you trying to query an existing collection? Are you sure that there actually are documents in the collection called `students`?

Comment: yes i am try to get data from my existing collection. yes there are documents in the collection named student

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an existing collection that you want to query using Mongoose, you should pass the name of that collection to the schema explicitly:

```
var studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... }, { collection : 'student' });
```

If you don't, Mongoose will generate a collection name for you, by lowercasing *and pluralizing* the model name (so documents for the model `Student` will be stored in the collection called `students`; notice the trailing `-s`).

More documentation [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection).