# How to export from a module in express from a mongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I know this could sound a basic question, but I am new to Express, Node and Mongo DB.
I created this model Courses.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Create Schema
// var studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ ... }, { collection : 'student' });

const coursesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
},{ collection : 'courses' });



let Courses = mongoose.model('Courses', coursesSchema);
module.exports = Courses;
```

the results are consoled well enough in the terminal
but when I return the results and courses to module.exports and then use it in the index.js it doesn't return anything on postman

Note that when I use simple JS in the model it exports and return data well enough. i.e: this works:

```
const courses = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Data Structure',
        description: 'Data Structure with java',
        points: 100,
        image: 'public/photos/ds.png',
        media: 'media'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Django',
        description: 'python framework',
        points: 30,
        image: 'public/photos/django.png',
        media: 'media'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Adonis JS',
        description: 'JS framework',
        points: 50,
        image: 'public/photos/adonis.png',
        media: 'media'
    }
];

module.exports = courses;
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');


const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://mohisham:13dhsbbs4680@coursesdb-welku.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true  });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', function(){
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB successfully!");
});
db.on('error', function(){
    console.log(err);
});

const logger = require('./middleware/logger');
const members = require('./Members');
const courses = require('./Courses');
// const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const app = express();


app.use('/api/courses', require('./routes/api/courses'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
```

routes/api/courses.js

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const courses = require('../../Courses');



router.get('/', (req, res) => res.json(courses));

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Reading up on asynchronous programming in javascript would be helpful for you to understand the difference between the two examples. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous

Comment: @MatthewWeeks I edited the question, but still there is a problem, could you elaborate more?

Comment: Hey there, are you sure about the notation `let Courses = module.exports = mongoose.model('Courses', coursesSchema);`?  I have never seen it. I would use something like  `let Courses = mongoose.model('Courses', coursesSchema);` and then `module.exports = Courses ` In the example that works you are doing something similar, it seems correct in the example that works.

Comment: Another point, when you define the schema, you are using a second argument `{ collection : 'courses' }` are you sure it is correct? what are you trying to accomplish? I would remove it, I have never used it.

Comment: @JorgePires You are right about the first point. I edited it but still nothing new. Regarding the second argument check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39941870/how-to-fetch-data-from-mongodb-using-nodejs-expressjs

Comment: Let me see if I understood properly, if you replace the schema with the hardcoded data, in the same file, it works?

Comment: in  the example you sent me, they say if you are connecting to an existing collection, are you?

Comment: @JorgePires Yes there is a collection I have created. and Yes the hardcoded JS works

Comment: did you try, just to make sure, to connect by default to a new collection, just see if it works. Create just one data, just to make sure that it is not the problem.

Comment: @JorgePires BTW I can console the data in the collection in a MongoClient function

Comment: @JorgePires there is data in the Database and it can be fetched. The problem is in exporting this data

Comment: I bellieve the problem is here `router.get('/', (req, res) => res.json(courses));`

Comment: You are sending the query

Comment: Please, try this `router.get('/', async (req, res) => res.json( await courses.find()));` and on  it should see all the contect

Comment: and let know what comes out!

Comment: @JorgePires this printed an empty array []

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210037/discussion-between-jorge-pires-and-mhisham).

Comment: @mhisham how is it going?

Comment: @JorgePires Nothing new. Still using the hardcode data until I find some solution :(

Comment: can you send me the code using something like github? I could run some tests, or maybe by skype, what is best for you.

Comment: We could also try using teamviewer, or go on as yesterday, bu chatting, what is best for you

Comment: @JorgePires the whole code is up their. I hid nothing but the db url. Currently I will have to finish the whole API task regardless of whether it works or not :(. so I won't be able to use skype

Comment: can you send me the link?